# Icons not showing when optimizations are enabled with Bootstrap 3.0.1 and ASP .NET MVC 4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.1 with ASP .NET MVC 4 and I want to display some icons, like with:

```
<i class="icon-remove"></i>
```

Here is my Bootstrap bundle.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/CSS/bootstrap").Include(
    "~/Content/Bootstrap/body.css",
    "~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css",
    "~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-mvc-validation.css",
    "~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css",
    "~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.css"
    ));
```

But when I enable optimizations, it looks like there is no icon CSS classes in the bundle.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

When I open the /CSS/bootstrap?v=8eAoW9V58s_Xu995JPPD57vwG8ohFZpa5QzR95hDcow1 file I don't find the .icon-remove class whereas I see it in bootstrap.css.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain since I use font awesome icons in my app but it looks like they changed the values from `icon-` to `glyphicon-`

So `icon-remove` became:
`glyphicon glyphicon-remove`

[Bootsrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll try to update Bootstrap.

But the problem is that I see the .icon-remove class in bootstrap.css but not in the bundle. I update the question.